# Match Data in a Multiple Column

Tags: sql

I have a 20 Column in a Table Col1, Col2, Col3 .... Col20. 
RowNo column is a primary column, Col1 to Col20 is a not null int column

in each Column has unique data for single row(means Col1 has 10 so in Col2 to Col20 values is not repeat). table has approx 100000 records.

i have a 10 values like 18, 3, 15, 16, 11, 5, 41, 61, 43, 80 i want to search each records in all 20 column.

select only those rows which has all 10 values in col1 to col20

For Ex. 18 can be match in col1 to col20

as per the below data return 4th row result may be return more then one row

[image]

Comment: Add data as text, then we can copy/paste it to sql-fiddle.

Comment: Does your table have a primary key / unique ID field, in addition to the columns `col1` to `col20`?

Comment: RowNo column is a primary column, Col1 to Col20 is a not null int column

Comment: What SGBD do you target?

Comment: i am using MSSQL-2008. 
Can not understand what the wrong with this question so other user vote in minus

Comment: I did not downvote, but it's probably that your database design is considered a bad approach. My answer below shows how these data should better be stored in a db.

Comment: actually we are working on a lottery system and we can not change the db design because of it will contains lot of data so we have to find out a solution from existing design. but thanks a lot for your solution. my last comments not for you comment for who did minus voting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM
yourTable
WHERE
  CASE WHEN 18 IN (col1, col2, col3, ...col20) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN  3 IN (col1, col2, col3, ...col20) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN 15 IN (col1, col2, col3, ...col20) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN 16 IN (col1, col2, col3, ...col20) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN 11 IN (col1, col2, col3, ...col20) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN  5 IN (col1, col2, col3, ...col20) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN 41 IN (col1, col2, col3, ...col20) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN 61 IN (col1, col2, col3, ...col20) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN 43 IN (col1, col2, col3, ...col20) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
+ CASE WHEN 80 IN (col1, col2, col3, ...col20) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
= 10
```

Answer (score 0):

An Alternative: Copy your data into a query-friendly table.

The table:

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblX](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [ColN] [int] NULL,
        [Value] [int] NULL,
        [RowNo] [int] NULL
    );
```

Copy data over:

```
    INSERT INTO tblX(RowNo, ColN, Value)
    SELECT RowNo, 1, Col1 FROM tblCols;
    INSERT INTO tblX(RowNo, ColN, Value)
    SELECT RowNo, 2, Col2 FROM tblCols;
    INSERT INTO tblX(RowNo, ColN, Value)
    SELECT RowNo, 3, Col3 FROM tblCols;
    INSERT INTO tblX(RowNo, ColN, Value)
    ...
    INSERT INTO tblX(RowNo, ColN, Value)
    SELECT RowNo, 20, Col20 FROM tblCols;
```

The query:

```
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        tblX
        WHERE RowNo IN 
        (
                SELECT 
                    RowNo
                FROM
                    tblX
                WHERE
                    Value IN (18, 3, 15, 16, 11, 5, 41, 61, 43, 80)
                GROUP BY RowNo
                HAVING COUNT(*) = 10 -- the number of numbers above
         ) 
    ORDER BY RowNo, ColN
```

Answer (score 0):

you first get the filter value as a comma separated, and then using below function get it in a table in different rows

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
@String VARCHAR(200),
@Delimiter VARCHAR(5)
)

RETURNS @SplittedValues TABLE
(
OccurenceId SMALLINT IDENTITY(1,1),
SplitValue VARCHAR(200)
)

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @SplitLength INT

WHILE LEN(@String) > 0
BEGIN

SELECT @SplitLength = (CASE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) WHEN 0 THEN

LEN(@String) ELSE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) -1 END)

INSERT INTO @SplittedValues

SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,1,@SplitLength)

SELECT @String = (CASE (LEN(@String) - @SplitLength) WHEN 0 THEN ''

ELSE RIGHT(@String, LEN(@String) - @SplitLength - 1) END)

END

RETURN
```

now declare a cusor for this table to get one by one value

now in side this cursor using

```
SELECT s.name SchemaName, t.name TableName, c.name ColumnName
FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN
     sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id INNER JOIN
     sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
;
```

get all the columns of one row in different rows and run loop of it and check with it filter value,
basically inside above cursor you have to run another cursor

its ugly, lengthy , but better than nothing :-)

Answer (score 0):

before your answer i am use below function which is return me a match count and get where count = 10

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[MatchRows]
(
    @id int, 
    @No1 int, 
    @No2 int,
    @No3 int,
    @No4 int,
    @No5 int,
    @No6 int,
    @No7 int,
    @No8 int,
    @No9 int,
    @No10 int   
)
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @ReturnVal bit = 0; 
    Declare @Allvalue varchar(max);
    Declare @CntMatch int;

    SELECT  @Allvalue = ',' + Convert(varchar(3),No1)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No2)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No3)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No4)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No5)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No6)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No7)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No8)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No9)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No10)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No11)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No12)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No13)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No14)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No15)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No16)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No17)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No18)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No19)+ ',' +
                        Convert(varchar(3),No20)+ ','
    FROM    DrawFinalResult
    WHERE   ID = @ID;

    SET @CntMatch = 0;

    Select @CntMatch += (CASE  WHEN CHARINDEX(','+ Convert (varchar(3),@No1) +',',@Allvalue) > 0 THEN 1 Else 0 END); 
    Select @CntMatch += (CASE  WHEN CHARINDEX(','+ Convert (varchar(3),@No2) +',',@Allvalue) > 0 THEN 1 Else 0 END); 
    Select @CntMatch += (CASE  WHEN CHARINDEX(','+ Convert (varchar(3),@No3) +',',@Allvalue) > 0 THEN 1 Else 0 END); 
    Select @CntMatch += (CASE  WHEN CHARINDEX(','+ Convert (varchar(3),@No4) +',',@Allvalue) > 0 THEN 1 Else 0 END); 
    Select @CntMatch += (CASE  WHEN CHARINDEX(','+ Convert (varchar(3),@No5) +',',@Allvalue) > 0 THEN 1 Else 0 END); 
    Select @CntMatch += (CASE  WHEN CHARINDEX(','+ Convert (varchar(3),@No6) +',',@Allvalue) > 0 THEN 1 Else 0 END); 
    Select @CntMatch += (CASE  WHEN CHARINDEX(','+ Convert (varchar(3),@No7) +',',@Allvalue) > 0 THEN 1 Else 0 END); 
    Select @CntMatch += (CASE  WHEN CHARINDEX(','+ Convert (varchar(3),@No8) +',',@Allvalue) > 0 THEN 1 Else 0 END); 
    Select @CntMatch += (CASE  WHEN CHARINDEX(','+ Convert (varchar(3),@No9) +',',@Allvalue) > 0 THEN 1 Else 0 END); 
    Select @CntMatch += (CASE  WHEN CHARINDEX(','+ Convert (varchar(3),@No10) +',',@Allvalue) > 0 THEN 1 Else 0 END); 

    Set @ReturnVal = (CASE WHEN @CntMatch = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);

    RETURN @ReturnVal
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You also can use `unpivot` to reduce typing `col1, col2, ..., colN` (especially if it will differ in future). You can try smth like this:

```
create table Unpivoted (RoNo int, Value int primary key)

insert Unpivoted
select
  upvt.RoNo, upvt.Value
from (
  select * from YourTable
) src
unpivot (
  Value for ColNo in (
    col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, 
    col6, col7, col8, col9, col10 -- etc.
  )
) upvt

select
  *
from YourTable yt
join (
  select
    RoNo
  from Unpivoted
  where
    Value in (
      18, 3, -- etc. N values at all
    )
  group by
    RoNo
  having
    count(*) = N
) x on 
  yt.RoNo = x.RoNo

drop table Unpivoted
```